# CRAN/R: Concatenate a column into a list of string-pairs in the form "WX-YZ, AB-WX, AB-YZ"

Tags: r, variables, concatenation, dummy-variable, cran

My dput is given below.

**What I want to do**: For every `group` (which is unique in the dataset), I'm trying to construct a new variable, say, `countrypairlist`, that lists all country PAIRS for each group. You'll see that that this desired information is implicitly contained in the above data in two separate ways.

First, the variable `countries` list all relevant countries for a particular `group` (e.g., for the first row, there's only one country, `JP`). Second, the dummy variables named after `countries` (e.g., the variable `JP`) `== 1` if the name of that dummy variable is listed in the variable `countries` for a particular group, and `== 0` otherwise.

Using either set of variables (whichever is easier and more computationally efficient), I want to create the `countrypairlist` that lists all country pairs, separated by ", ". For example, for `group == 4253247`, I'd need `countrypairlist == LI-BE, LI-NL, BE-NL` (order doesn't matter, so long as all pairs are listed).  As another example, for `group == 27439823`, I'd need `countrypairlist == DK-CH, DK-DE, CH-DE`. `countrypairlist` can equal `NA` or `0` or any other placeholder when there is only one country in `countries` (or equivalently, when `rowSum(over dummy variables) == 1`.

What would be the most effective way to do this? Thank you!

```
structure(list(group = c(26344962L, 26947173L, 7681129L, 32322556L, 
27784632L, 34854057L, 37831629L, 37903977L, 38752541L, 35655241L, 
39744060L, 39864671L, 38513906L, 39829036L, 39768832L, 39682597L, 
39789349L, 40566389L, 39760845L, 39832290L, 39870577L, 40032764L, 
39743044L, 35519833L, 34609489L, 39734460L, 39744800L, 7672727L, 
32313557L, 34957472L, 39643836L, 39616295L, 4257105L, 26020976L, 
4253247L, 39410092L, 38187175L, 39204726L, 39294100L, 39294069L, 
39226773L, 39231044L, 39410460L, 39284069L, 27407686L, 10861963L, 
18556217L, 27481648L, 26068821L, 27439823L), countries = c("JP", 
"US", "DE", "NL", "JP", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE, DD", "DE, US", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE, AT", "DE, AT", "DE", "DE", "CH", 
"CH, DE", "AT", "CH, AT, US", "DE", "LI, BE, NL", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "US, DE", "DE", "DE", "US, AU, FR", "NL, GB, US", 
"JP", "JP", "CH, SE, DK", "DK, CH, DE"), JP = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), US = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), DE = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), NL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AT = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), CH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), LI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FR = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), GB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), DK = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), AU = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(countrypairlist = sapply(strsplit(df$countries, ", "), function(x) {
    if(length(x) == 1) return(x)
    paste(apply(combn(x, 2), 2, paste, collapse = "-"), collapse = ";")
  })) %>%
  select(group, countries, countrypairlist)
#>       group  countries   countrypairlist
#> 1  26344962         JP                JP
#> 2  26947173         US                US
#> 3   7681129         DE                DE
#> 4  32322556         NL                NL
#> 5  27784632         JP                JP
#> 6  34854057         DE                DE
#> 7  37831629         DE                DE
#> 8  37903977         DE                DE
#> 9  38752541         DE                DE
#> 10 35655241         DE                DE
#> 11 39744060         DE                DE
#> 12 39864671         DE                DE
#> 13 38513906         DE                DE
#> 14 39829036         DE                DE
#> 15 39768832     DE, DD             DE-DD
#> 16 39682597     DE, US             DE-US
#> 17 39789349         DE                DE
#> 18 40566389         DE                DE
#> 19 39760845         DE                DE
#> 20 39832290         DE                DE
#> 21 39870577         DE                DE
#> 22 40032764         DE                DE
#> 23 39743044         DE                DE
#> 24 35519833         DE                DE
#> 25 34609489         DE                DE
#> 26 39734460     DE, AT             DE-AT
#> 27 39744800     DE, AT             DE-AT
#> 28  7672727         DE                DE
#> 29 32313557         DE                DE
#> 30 34957472         CH                CH
#> 31 39643836     CH, DE             CH-DE
#> 32 39616295         AT                AT
#> 33  4257105 CH, AT, US CH-AT;CH-US;AT-US
#> 34 26020976         DE                DE
#> 35  4253247 LI, BE, NL LI-BE;LI-NL;BE-NL
#> 36 39410092         DE                DE
#> 37 38187175         DE                DE
#> 38 39204726         DE                DE
#> 39 39294100         DE                DE
#> 40 39294069         DE                DE
#> 41 39226773         DE                DE
#> 42 39231044     US, DE             US-DE
#> 43 39410460         DE                DE
#> 44 39284069         DE                DE
#> 45 27407686 US, AU, FR US-AU;US-FR;AU-FR
#> 46 10861963 NL, GB, US NL-GB;NL-US;GB-US
#> 47 18556217         JP                JP
#> 48 27481648         JP                JP
#> 49 26068821 CH, SE, DK CH-SE;CH-DK;SE-DK
#> 50 27439823 DK, CH, DE DK-CH;DK-DE;CH-DE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>